# How to un-hash a hashed value in impala?

Tags: hadoop, impala

Below is the Impala query we used for hashing value:

```
SELECT 
LOWER(HEX(FNV_HASH(concat('***', cast(PATID as string),'apSxZxTAaA3Wnnsv'))))
AS PATID
```

So we would like to un-hash this hashed value for research team in Impala.

Comment: @Clément: thanks for wanting to improve this question. It was correct to add a code block for the query, but the inline code formatting was inappropriate, and I can't think why you added it. Please only use this for code, console commands, system I/O etc.

Comment: Jyothi, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer yes my fault, I read it again and it was totally a nonsense. I'd misunderstood the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

hashing a data value reduces the amount of information that goes in. You cannot unhash a value with 100% certainity as collision is always possible.

Comment: Furthermore, a good hashing system requires brute-force searching to reverse it, so if a hash really needs to be reversed then a hash probably is  not the right solution.